# How can the Cox proportional hazard model be formatted into a generalized linear model?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, survival, cox-model

Is the Cox proportional hazard model a generalized linear model and how is formulated?

Comment: The MLE from a conditional Poisson model (where you "split" the data at unique failure times) and from a Cox model are identical. A couple of references: (1) Xu, Stanley, et al. "Fitting parametric and semi-parametric conditional Poisson regression models with Cox’s partial likelihood in self-controlled case series and matched cohort studies." J Data Sci 8 (2010): 349-360. (2) 
Royston, P., and P. C. Lambert. 2011. Flexible parametric survival analysis using Stata: beyond the Cox model. College Station, TX: Stata Press. (section 4.5.1).

Comment: I should add: in the presence of tied events, the equivalence is between conditional Poisson model and Cox model with Breslow method for ties.